# Call javascript function from windows service c#

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-services, browser

I need to call a javascript function inside a chrome-window from a windows service written in c#.

The browser is entirely at my disposal so I can configuration is no problem.

For example, the windows service is a file checker, when a certain file is changed there has to popup a js alert.

-EDIT-

The following works fine for client to client communication (server-side code).
So when a specific event happens on the server I can display this on the client (I hoped commented would do that)

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;
using SignalR.Hosting.Self;
using SignalR.Hubs;

namespace Net.SignalR.SelfHost
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://localhost:8081/";

            var server = new Server(url);
            server.MapHubs();

            server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("SignalR server started at " + url);


            Console.ReadLine();

           // Clients[collection].flush("bericht: " + message + collection);

        }

        //public void PushMessage(string bericht)
        //{
        //    var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8081/");
        //    var serverHub = hubConnection.CreateProxy("CollectionHub");

        //    serverHub.On("flush", message => System.Console.WriteLine(message));
        //    hubConnection.Start().Wait();
        //    serverHub.Invoke("Subscribe", "Product");
        //    string line = null;
        //    while ((line = bericht) != null)
        //    {
        //        serverHub.Invoke("Publish", line, "Product").Wait();
        //    }

        //    System.Console.Read();
        //}



        public class CollectionHub : Hub
        {

            public void Subscribe(string collectionName)
            {
                Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, collectionName);
                Console.WriteLine("Subscribed to: " + collectionName);
                //serverHub.Invoke("Publish", "dit is een eerste test", "Product").Wait();



            }

            public Task Unsubscribe(string collectionName)
            {
                return Clients[collectionName].leave(Context.ConnectionId);
            }

            public void Publish(string message, string collection)
            {
                Clients[collection].flush("bericht: " + message + collection);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can i ask what the problem is you're trying to solve (the bigger problem not that of calling a javascript function)

Comment: Sending data to the server, process this data on the server and send it back to the client to update a view is way to slow, so I would like to show that it's loading before the data is back from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are describing [SignalR](http://signalr.net/).

> **What is ASP.NET SignalR?**
>
> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET
>   developers that makes it incredibly simple to add real-time web
>   functionality to your applications. What is "real-time web"
>   functionality? It's the ability to have your server-side code push
>   content to the connected clients as it happens, in real-time.
>
> You may have heard of WebSockets, a new HTML5 API that enables
>   bi-directional communication between the browser and server. SignalR
>   will use WebSockets under the covers when it's available, and
>   gracefully fallback to other techniques and technologies when it
>   isn't, while your application code stays the same.
>
> SignalR also provides a very simple, high-level API for doing server
>   to client RPC (call JavaScript functions in your clients' browsers
>   from server-side .NET code) in your ASP.NET application, as well as
>   adding useful hooks for connection management, e.g. connect/disconnect
>   events, grouping connections, authorization.
>
> **What can you do with ASP.NET SignalR?**
>
> SignalR can be used to add any
>   sort of "real-time" web functionality to your ASP.NET application.
>   While chat is often used as an example, you can do a whole lot more.
>   Any time a user refreshes a web page to see new data, or the page
>   implements Ajax long polling to retrieve new data, is candidate for
>   using SignalR.

What it basicly does, is giving you access to the client AND server side functions in both directions, a simple example of it's usage can be found on the [asp.net website](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) which will give you a good idea on how to use it and what it's capable of doing.

Comment: So I setup signalR locally and connect to the client that way. I'm going to try that out. Thank you.

Comment: Client to Client & Client to Server communication is working but now I would like to push 'messages' from the server to the client and I cannot get this working

Comment: In the example it is shown how to do this right? the 'Clients.All.broadcastMessage(..,..)' part?

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using something like signal IR to do that, its what its designed for, essentially you are describing real time functionality;

Signal IR can be found [here](http://signalr.net/) and has a great section on javascript in its [wiki](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki)

In particular you probably want to take a look at [Hubs](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client)